# Django page not found, help would be appreciated

Tags: python, django

I was taking a youtube tutorial on making a basic website using django and I got this error when coding:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

app/
admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

This is my code:

For urls.py/mysite:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('app/', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

For views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world!")
```

For urls.py/myapp:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Since you write `path('app/', include('myapp.urls')),`, you access the `index` view through `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add root level path to access the path you specified **http://127.0.0.1:8000/**:

*urls.py/mysite*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('app/', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

*views.py/mysite*

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('This is home page')
```

Comment: I am getting this when I add on path('', views.index, name='home'),     File "/Users/frankie/Documents/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
NameError: name 'views' is not defined

Comment: import your views like: ```from . import views```

Comment: from . import views                                                                ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'mysite' (/Users/frankie/Documents/mysite/mysite/__init__.py)

Comment: If you have view.py in mysite. Else, you have to create views.py and make a function called index.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified:

```
path('app/', include('myapp.urls')),
```

It means all the paths in `myapp.urls` are prefixed with `app/`. So you can access the index view with: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/`. Or if you want to access the `index` view with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` you rewrite the path to:

```
path('', include('myapp.urls')),
```